# Current measurement in every 20ms

Tags: current, measurement

I want to measure the current in every 20 ms and record the measurement. I was using the Fluke DMM and in that I am not able to measure something less than 125 ms. Could someone suggest any methods for the measurement?

I was using Fluke 8845A DMM. Any suggestion is acceptable (with fluke DMM or without it)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Data Acquisition (DAQ)

There are many DAQs available online and their datasheets will specify the minimum sample rates. It will depend on your budget